# Integration tests for secure endpoint in quarkus

Tags: java, mockito, integration-testing, quarkus, nimbus-jose-jwt

I have a quarkus application, created a custom annotation with interceptor to secure endpoints.

// Custom annotation

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface PermitRole {
}
```

//Interceptor binded with annotation

```
@Interceptor
@PermitRole
public class LiveTraderRolesAuthorization { 
   @Inject
   HttpHeaders headers;

   @Inject
   JWTTokenParser jwtTokenParser;

   @AroundInvoke
   public Object authorize(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
       // here i have logic to ***parse Authorization header JWT token using nimbus-jose*** and setting authorized flag. 
      if(authorized) {
        return context.proceed();
      }
    }
}
```

// my controller method

```
    @GET
    @PermitRole
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public RestResponse<MResponse> getSome(@PathParam("Id") String Id) {
        //logic
    }
```

***Question :*** Now integration tests for my controller is failing after adding the custom annotation. One way to solve this is I can mock JWTTokenParser in tests and return the mocked claims, But is there a better way to write integration tests for interceptor and controller together so that whole interceptor and token parsing logic can be tested like real application.
Really appreciate any help !!

***NOTE***: I am using nimbus-jose-jwt library to parse the Jwt token, not anything specific to quarkus.

Comment: The answer by @Serkan suggests (or could be interpreted as suggesting) that you drop your custom security solution and adopt the Quarkus built-in solution. There's an extension for JWT, integrated with the Quarkus security system. That's what I would also recommend. If you don't want that, my question to your question would be: how are you generating the JWT token in your integration test? I would expect your JWT parsing library to also include a JWT generating API, that's likely the best thing to use. Can you show the code of your test?

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties define an apart JWT for your tests:

```
%test.smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=dummy-private-key.pem
%test.mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=dummy-public-key.pem 
%test.mp.jwt.verify.issuer=test-issuer
```

And now you can use this token in your test:

```
String jwt = Jwt.sign("test-claims.json");

@Test
void authentication() {
   given().oauth2().bearer(this.jwt)
   .when() //etc
}
```

Note that your roles in the claims should be called “groups”, that’s what Quarkus expects. There is also a configuration to change this.

The other way to test, is to include quarkus-security-test dependency in your pom.xml.
Read the “Test” section of the documentation for this: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt

Comment: I am using nimbus-jose + jwt lirary to parse the token, I don't want to add a new library just for tests.

Comment: If you don’t use quarkus-jwt(-build)& quarkus-test-security, then you’re on your own. Good luck.

Comment: I can use quarkus-test-security-jwt for testing if it works with my curren tokenParser and it should work I guess, In tokenparser I have a jwks url, which return the keyset to verify the JWT token, Now I am confused that what should be this JWKS keyset(it requires every key I guess, kid, key, n, e etc. what dummy values should i set for them using quarkus-test-security-jwt ) so that it parse the token passed from  my tests generated by quarkus-test-security-jwt .